# How to Escape a Plus Sign in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping, cdata

I am using XSLT version 1.0 to take data from an XML passed to our system and put data into a text file used by another system.

When I get a certain value from the XML, I want to pass the data: 5+ years.  However, all I'm getting in the text file is 5 years.  I don't know why its not passing the + sign.  Every other value works.

I have researched this online and tried numerous things including using various combinations of CDATA and disable-output-escaping with both xsl:text and xsl:value-of, but nothing works.

Here is a cut down version of the XSLT I want to use and the XML used to test it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
   <xsl:template name="YRS">
      <xsl:for-each select="/HOME/YRS">
         <xsl:variable name="HomeSub" select="position()"/>
         <yrs-rec reclen="88" rectype="YRS">
            <yrs-rec-typ format="xxx" type="c" precision="0" pos="1" len="3">YRS</yrs-rec-typ>
            <yrs-rec-nbr format="9(3)" type="nu" precision="0" pos="5" len="3">
               <xsl:value-of select="$HomeSub"/>
            </yrs-rec-nbr>
            <yrs-lgth-of-own format="x(50)" type="c" precision="0" pos="39" len="50">
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="len_of_own = 'E'">&lt; 1 month</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="len_of_own = 'A'">&lt; 1 year</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="len_of_own = 'B'">1-2 years</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="len_of_own = 'C'">3-4 years</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="len_of_own = 'D'">5+ years</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="len_of_own = 'X'"/>
                  <xsl:otherwise/>
               </xsl:choose>
            </yrs-lgth-of-own>
         </yrs-rec>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>



<HOME>
    <YRS>
        <len_of_own>A</len_of_own>
    </YRS>
    <YRS>
        <len_of_own>B</len_of_own>
    </YRS>
    <YRS>
        <len_of_own>C</len_of_own>
    </YRS>
    <YRS>
        <len_of_own>D</len_of_own>
    </YRS>
    <YRS>
        <len_of_own>E</len_of_own>
    </YRS>
    <YRS>
        <len_of_own>X</len_of_own>
    </YRS>
</HOME>
```

I am not able to edit any other part of the XSLT... only my section for yrs-lgth-of-own.  I dont know what else to do to get this to work, please help!

I am new here, so sorry if I have not provided enough information.  Let me know what other information is needed.  Thanks!

Comment: The standard character sequence for a plus sign is `&#43;`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi bitfiddler.  Thank you, yes I did try that, but still the plus sign disappears.

Comment: The stylesheet you have added has one named template and it is never called. As such, it wouldn't do anything except use the built-in template rules to copy all the text nodes as is. I suspect there is some other mechanism at work here - esp. since you say that "*I am not able to edit any other part of the XSLT.*".

Comment: Apologies, I guess I should have removed that line.  Yes, many templates are used to build various records that are all called by one "parent" template.  If I change any of these other templates or any other part of the XSLT above, that will impact many other things that already exist.  I only want to add this piece into the existing text file I'm passing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to escape the plus sign in any way. A simple:

```
<xsl:text>5+ years</xsl:text>
```

is *all* that should be required. If you're not getting the expected result, there must a problem elsewhere in your processing chain.

Comment: and CDATA sections and disable-output-escaping will get you nowhere. Try to provide a complete repro: source document and stylesheet that other people can run, to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Thank you.  Now this code used to be located in another module and it used to work just as you said, but now that we've moved the code, the plus sign disappears.  The only difference I see between the modules is that mine has the .xsl extension and the other one has the .xslt extension.  Could that cause a difference?  I'm not sure what you mean by a complete repro... sorry I've coded in XSLT many times before but I wouldn't say I'm a master.  More like a took a beginner class and taught myself the rest over the years.

Comment: @J.Cooper I don't follow your description. What is a module? And how are you running the transformation? --- Please post a minimal, but complete example - one that can be run as is (just by copying the XML and XSLT) - that produces the problem - see:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oh I see.  Okay, let me try, thank you!  Also, I was trying to say we have 2 different sets of code we use for 2 different systems and I'm trying to figure out why the plus sign works in one and not the other.  The code in the system where the plus sign worked has an extension of .xslt.  My set of code where the plus sign doesn't work has the extension of .xsl.  I don't know if that has anything to do with it.  If not, maybe there is some other difference.

Comment: I don't think the extension should matter - but I don't know what you're using to call the transformation. As i said in my answer, the problem is not with the actual XSLT code.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what is used to call it.  Let me think about/research that.  In the meantime, I have created a cut down version of the XML and XSLT... I'm just trying to figure out how to attach them... or do I post it right in the text box?

Comment: "*I'm not sure what is used to call it.*" Well, it doesn't happen on its own... --- "*how to attach them..*"  Just edit your question and add them there (as code).

Comment: I'm aware, but I believe another system handles that.  I'm just not sure how it all works together... yet.  I have added the XSLT and XML above, thank you!

Comment: I'm still trying to find out whats used to run the XSLT but I am outputting to a text file.  The other set of code where it works outputs to another XML file.  Could there be any difference there?

Comment: @J.Cooper I don't want to guess. If you can provide a complete set of XML + XSLT that can be used to reproduce the problem, then we can trace down the cause. Right now, you're complaining about headache and showing us an X-Ray of your knee. The only suggestion I can make is this: change the text "5+ years" in your XSLT to "5+ XYZ". Then observe if the result is "5 XYZ". I suspect it might not be.